# Выборочный вывод переменных из функции

Tags: php, функции, переменные

Как реализовать, что-то подобное?

```
function output_vars()
{
$a="грибочки маринованные, вкусненькие";
$b="сальцо солёненькое, аппетитное";
$c="огурчики солёненькие, хрустящие";
$d="100 гр. холодненькой";

return $a;
return $b;
return $c;
return $d;
}
//как вывести, допустим только переменную $b
$b=output_vars(/*как её тут обозначить, если присвоение значения для неё происходит в функции?*/);
print $b."<br>";
```

Comment: А может просто массив:$a=array('яблоки','грибы','огурцы'); return $a[$n];  А $n - параметр с номером элемента в массиве, ну или именем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагая, что это только пример, то оставляем функцию на месте

```
function output_vars()
{
    return [
        'a' => "грибочки маринованные, вкусненькие",
        'b' => "сальцо солёненькое, аппетитное",
        'c' => "огурчики солёненькие, хрустящие",
        'd' => "100 гр. холодненькой",
    ];
}

$b = output_vars()['b'];
```

Но если в функции содержится только определение массива, то тогда надо оставить только его, а функцию убрать совсем.

Comment: В создании переменной учавствуют ещё и результаты запросов к БД через `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`
Поэтому и затык в моей голове происходит.
Вставляю $b = output_vars()['b']; в while и результата ноль.

Comment: Делать надо только осмысленные вещи. То есть, сначала надо понять, зачем "вставлять $b = output_vars()['b']; в while", и только потом уже надеяться получить хоть какой-то результат.

Comment: ладно, открою "карты". Вот то, за чем оно нужно.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487781/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F-php-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Спасибо! Передал в функцию значение массива от SQL и всё заработало.