# Нужна идея (php вывод переменных)

Tags: php, функции, переменные

Есть громоздкое body от table

```
print "
    <tr style='background-color:$color;'>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'>
            <a href='edit.php?id=".$row['number']."'>".$row['number']."</a>
        </td>
        <td id='table_style'>
            <a href='edit.php?id=".$row['number']."'>".$row['family']."</a>
        </td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['birthdate']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['passport']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['organization']."</td>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'>".$row['passport_date']."</td>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'>".$row['organization_code']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['telephone']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['user_files']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['ip_address']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['description']."</td>
    </tr>
";
```

Вывод происходит после

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_cart", $db) or die("you have trable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
// тут выводится это самое body от table.
}
```

Таблица выводится при многочисленных операциях и фильтрах.
т.е. если нужно заменить\убрать какие-то столбцы, то приходится править тело таблицы в 10 разных местах в коде (где оно формируется).
Пробовал написать функцию вывода, не осилил.
Как можно оптимизировать данное примитивное решение?

Comment: Для начала надо научиться писать свой код, чтобы он был виден на странице ВЕСЬ. И не приходилось мотать два часа чтобы его увидеть

Comment: @I_CaR Вам нужен какой нибудь простенький шаблонизатор. Строка html должна лежать отдельно и в ней в нужных местах стоят названия переменных, в каком нибудь понятном скрипту виде. При получении данных из базы шаблонизатор берет строку и подменяет в ней все встреченные имена переменных на их значения из массива $row

Answer (score 1):

реализовал так:

```
function print_table($row)
{
    if ($_SESSION['Access']=="admin")
    {
        $table_body= "<tr style='background-color:$color;'>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['number']."'>".$row['number']."</a></td>
        <td id='table_style'><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['number']."'>".$row['family']." ".$row['name']." ".$row['patronymic']."</a></td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['birthdate']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['passport']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['organization']."</td>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'>".$row['passport_date']."</td>
        <td id='table_style' align='center'>".$row['organization_code']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['telephone']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['user_files']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['ip_address']."</td>
        <td id='table_style'>".$row['description']."</td>
        </tr>";
    };

};

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_cart", $db) or die("you have trable");    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$table_body=print_table($row);
print $table_body[1];
}
```

Comment: За то минус?
(3 символа нужно)

Answer (score -2):

оптимизировать можно разбив на ячейки: 
так как это одна строчка (table row) то лучше разбить на ***

или изначально генерировать форматированный код, который меньше придется редактировать мотом.

или надо переделать всю логику скрипта. Иначе упрешся в стенку и потом надо будет доп функции писать чтобы исправить уже написанный ранее код.

Comment: Это мой код. Так что править ранее написанный код, в есть суть эволюции ПО.
Вы предложили какой-то вандер-пупер-вуфер костыль, на разработку которого уйдёт больше времени, чем на разработку нового аналогичного скрипта!
Теория должна быть бок о бок с реализацией (практикой). Ваш ответ какой-то утопический в реализации.

Comment: я не предлогал супер пупер костыль я предложил варианты. не понравилось, ну ладно, ок.